# Is there a way to Map the "Lead Owner" field?

Tags: formula

I need to upload a list into SF, using the Jitterbit tool. I need to map the lead owner field in SF with certain values on my .CSV file. I do not see "lead owner" as a mapping field to choose. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field API name is `OwnerId`. You will need to have the ID's for the owners in the .CSV you are importing.

Another free import tool, Dataloader.io can help you by finding the ID's for the owners on the import.

Comment: If I map the leads to their OwnerId , will it show up as their lead. For example, If I load a list of leads and put Bob's OwnerID number in the spreadsheet then will the lead owner in SF be Bob , or will they still be mine since I did the upload?

Comment: If you define an owner, then it will be that owner. If you leave it blank, then they will use your ID as the owner.

Comment: Brian, thanks for you help! How do I obtain the userID, I looked under the manage users page but I don't see it in there.

Comment: @Dan You can run a report on users. It will make it easy to export to excel.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @BrianChambers comments, if you load those records yourself without specifying an OwnerID, Ownership of the leads will automatically be assigned to you. You can optionally reassign the leads once uploaded doing a mass transfer or using your regular lead assignment rules.